# solr updating existing data in index vs inserting new data in index

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm using Solr 4 and am confused about updating existing data in an index.

According to the DataImportHandler Wiki:

*"delta-import* : For incremental imports and change detection run the
command `http://:/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import . It
supports the same clean, commit, optimize and debug parameters as
full-import command."

I know delta-import will find new data in the database and insert it into
the index. My problem is how it handles updates where I've got a record
that exists in the index and the database, the database record is changed
and I want to incorporate those changes in the existing record in the index.
IOW I don't want to insert it again.

I've tried this and wound up with 2 records with different key in the index.
The first contains the original db values found when the index was created,
the 2nd contains the db values after the record was changed.
"Greetings. I have a *solrj* client for fetching data from database. I am
using *delta-import* for fetching data. If a column is changed in database
using timestamp with *delta-import* i get the latest column indexed but
there are *duplicate* values in the index similar to the column but the data
is older. This works with cleaning the index but i want to update the index
without cleaning it. Is there a way to just update the index with the
updated column without having *duplicate* values. Appreciate for any
feedback.

Comment: The document that represent must have a unique key. Is there any in your case? any id which is unique? whats the <uniqueKey> in the schema.xml?

Comment: Yes i have a unique id. In my shema.xml i have <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

Comment: The problem is when a column is changed in database using timestamp with delta-import i get two records with different unique id because unique id is automatically generated

Comment: Then you have chosen a bad primary key. The one you have picked is a technical one. You need a key that reflects the identity of a record. The thing that may not be unique in terms of your RDBMS, but the thing to find the record.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945752/solr-dih-delta-import-with-compound-primary-keys

Comment: I have multiple tables with identical schema - table_a, table_b, table_c ... and I am trying to create one big index with the data from each of these tables in one data-config.xml file so i can not use a primary key   in my RDBMS as unique id.